# undefined method `table_name' for #<Arel::Table in ActiveAdmin/ransack

Tags: activeadmin, ransack

I was able to reproduce this error in activeadmin while using searching/filtering over text field(`filter :question, filters: [:cont]`)

> undefined method `table_name' for #<Arel::Table:0x00007efe88977f38 @name="cards", @klass=Card(id: integer, deck_id: integer, question: text, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime), @type_caster=#<ActiveRecord::TypeCaster::Map:0x00007efe88977df8 @klass=Card(id: integer, deck_id: integer, question: text, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)>, @table_alias=nil>

What's causing it and how to fix it?

```
ransack: 4.0.0
activeadmin(3-0-stable)
```

Comment: This error seems to be gone after upgrading to `ransack 4.1.0`. If you know more about this issue, please post an answer